# how to read .mat in fortran

Tags: matlab, fortran

can anyone tell me how to use fortran to read .mat?
I need to use fortran to process a 2d matrix from matlab.
I use

```
open(unit = 9006, file = 'zmatrix.mat',status = 'unknown', form = 'unformatted')
do i=1,296
    do j=1,278
    read(9006,*) zmatrix(i,j)
    end do
end do
```

but it is said fortran runtime error:format present for unformatted data transfer.
  Appreciated for any suggestions!

Comment: I think your question has an official answer by MATLAB developers: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/read-and-write-matlab-mat-files-in-c-c-and-fortran.html

Answer (score 0):

This little program reads a .mat file (name is first argument on exec line, i.e ./a.out Jet0500. The file contains a single two-dimensional variable,

```
!compile with gfortran Read_mesh.f90

Module Mat_Read

  real, allocatable :: omega(:,:)
contains

  Subroutine Read_mesh
    implicit none
    integer :: unitno=10
    integer :: kx,ncolumn,nrow
    character (len=30) :: filename
    call getarg(1,filename)
    open(unit=unitno,file=filename,form="formatted",&
         &status="old",action="read")
    do kx=1,3                   ! read by 3 lines
       read(unitno,fmt="(A1)")
    end do
    read(unitno,fmt="(8x,i14)")nrow
    read(unitno,fmt="(10x,i14)")ncolumn
    allocate (omega(nrow,ncolumn))
    do kx=1,nrow
       read(unitno,*) omega(kx,:)
    end do
    close(unitno)
  End Subroutine Read_mesh
End Module Mat_Read

Program test_Read_mesh
  use Mat_Read
  call Read_mesh
  print *,omega(1,1)       
End Program test_Read_mesh
```

Comment: thanks!When I run the code, it is said fatal error:can't open module file...for the line of "End Module Mat_Read"? I am using GNU Fortran

Comment: The program does compile without error for me.  Three things:  did you save it as a file w/ extension f90? Did the first line (Module..) get damaged during copying?  Finally, and this is unrelated to your compile problem, you will have to execute with e.g ./Read_mesh filename, where the file is a .mat file that has a single 2d variable.

Comment: what do you mean by "you will have to execute with e.g ./Read_mesh filename, where the file is a .mat file"? Do you mean I need to change the filename to the name of .mat?

Comment: Also, my .mat file is a 300 by 300 matrix.Thanks!

Comment: The test program knows which file to read from the first argument on the command line, which it gets through the call to 'getarg(1,filename)'. Assuming you copied the program to Read_mesh.f90 and compiled it with gfortran Read_mesh.f90, the executable is in a.out   To execute it you type ./a.out myfile.mat    where myfile.mat is the name of the file created by matlab.  It could be ANY name, and doesn't have to have the .mat extension.  The size of the array should be immaterial.  The .mat file has that information, and Read_mesh gets them and call them nrow and ncolumn